# Unparseable Date in Grails Domain Class from SQLite Database

Tags: sqlite, datetime, grails

I have a sqlite db (it is the spiceworks db) and I am mapping the tables to grails domain classes. There is a table in particular that is in a datetime format (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss). An example of such a date in the db for anyone who wants to verify would be: `2015-06-26 15:32:39`

I created the domain class and mapped my properties to the columns. Let grails generate the views so that they are default. When I try to get to the index page I get:

```
URI
/spiceworks/weeklyReportItem
Class
java.text.ParseException
Message
Unparseable date: "2015-06-26 15:32:39" does not match (\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q \E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q.\E(\p{Nd}++)
```

I've used MSSQL datetimes in the past and have never ran into this issue. In the database, the data type for the problematic column is datetime. Anyone know what's going on?

EDIT: I only have Read permissions on the db and the spiceworks source code isn't open source.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at that regular expression, you'll see it's looking for a ISO8601 timestamp formatted like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS.SSS` - in other words, it needs a decimal seconds, and you're just providing whole seconds.

An easy fix would be to update every existing value in the relevant column by appending `'.000'` to it, and update the insertion routines to do the same.

If you refer to the sqlite [date time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), there's a `%f` format specifier for `strftime()` that can be used to produce fractional seconds that might be helpful if you're building the timestamp directly in an insert query.

> In the database, the data type for the problematic column is datetime

Sqlite3 doesn't have a `datetime` type. The timestamps you're storing are strings. [More information](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype).

Comment: Is there a way to fix it without modifying the db? I don't have write permissions on it currently...I'm reporting on a copy of the production db. I COULD run some type of trigger that updates every date string to have those decimal seconds that you are referring to. But I need to do that every time since spiceworks leaves it off when doing inserts. Can that be done in SQLite or am I better off doing it in Grails?

Comment: @Bmoe I'm not familiar with grails or spiceworks. If there's no way to make the former more lenient about the format of data it accepts, then you have to adjust the data it's getting so it's in the format it's expecting. This could involve altering how the data is inserted into the database, updating it after insertion, or modifying the column text after getting it from the db with a select before passing it to grails (Or modifying it in the select of course).

Comment: The more I think about it, I think it would be better to have a process run through and add that decimal portion to the time. When I was initially creating this app I assumed I would be working off the production db but since I have a copy of it then I suppose I can alter where I need to. Is there anyway to create a scheduled SQLite task to update the columns? I only need to do it once a week.